# Cosa significa "svirgola" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Le città invisibili* d'Italo Calvino ho letto:

> «Ma la città non dice il suo passato, lo contiene come le linee di una mano, scritto negli spigoli delle vie, nelle griglie delle finestre, negli scorrimano delle scale, nelle antenne dei parafulmini, nelle aste delle bandiere, ogni segmento rigato a sua volta di graffi, seghettature, intagli, *svirgole*.»

Non capisco cosa significa "svirgole" in questa frase. Ho cercato il vocabolo "svirgola" in parecchi dizionari, ma nessuna delle definizioni che ho trovato sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000636.jpg), che cita come esempio questa stessa frase di Calvino, il significato di "svirgola" in questo contesto è il seguente:

> Graffio, segno, incisione ricurva.

Answer (score 9):

Dato il significato del verbo e il suo contesto, Calvino sta usando una licenza poetica per significare più o meno "curve" o meglio "curve appena accennate". "Svirgolare" è letteralmente il gesto che si fa con la mano quando si disegna una virgola, un gesto veloce, che appunto, abbozza una curva.

Comment: C'è una fonte a supporto di questa interpretazione? Quello che trovo online mi fa pensare che Calvino intendesse invece _colpi_ nel senso delle tracce che lasciano (come appunto _graffi_, _seghettature_ e _intagli_).

Comment: @Walter  Sì, sicuramente, dal verbo [svirgolare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/svirgolare/)

Comment: @mario quindi concordi con me, se capisco bene

Comment: @Walter  Sì 00000

Comment: @WalterTross: Parecchi anni dopo, si è trovata una fonte.